# SSH key randomart image changed when setting up

Tags: ssh

So I'm trying to setup an ssh key:

```
blank@host:~$ ssh-keygen
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 2048]----+
|+   ... ..  ...  |
|Eo  .. .  ...o.  |
|=.+. .   .. o+ . |
|.o  .   ... . o  |
|.+ .    S... .   |
|. o         .    |
| o               |
|                 |
|                 |
+-----------------+
```

After that's done, I did

```
blank@host:~$ ssh blank@host -o VisualHostKey=yes
The authenticity of host 'host' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is key.
+--[ED25519 256]--+
|        o = ..+  |
|       o o . * . |
|  E . o + o + +  |
| . o o   = . o + |
|  + . . S . . =  |
|   .         o o |
|            . .  |
|                 |
|                 |
+-----------------+
```

Is it normal that the key just changes like that?

Comment: One is RSA, the other ED25519.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first image is a visual fingerprint of a *personal identity key* that you have created using `ssh-keygen`, most likely stored in `~/.ssh/id_rsa`.

The second image is of (one of) the machine's *host keys*, `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub` assuming you are using typical installation defaults.

Personal keys identify you to the server; host keys identify the server to you.  Both may be used in an ssh connection; the host key is always used, a personal identity may be used with the `-i` option to `ssh` or the equivalent `IdentityFile` clause in an ssh configuration file (`/etc/ssh/ssh_config` for global configuration, or more likely `~/.ssh/config` for personal configuration).

You typically do not need to generate any host keys; an appropriate set of host keys is generated during the installation of openssh-server.  You can view the visual fingerprint of your existing hostkeys (for future visual confirmations) using

```
$ ssh-keygen -lvf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
```

or similarly for the other available host keys.